# How to pass a variable from an activity to a class?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app which users can store data in a activity called LIST. When the app starts, the user need to write the List Name. Than an Activity is showed with an EditText where the user could store some data.

The problem that I have is: I would like to make different tables in my database. One for each one of those Lists. So every time the user starts a new lists, it should create a new table. And the name of the tables would be defined by the user. Each list would have its table, and the name of the table would be the name of the list.

I am trying to get the List Name string using Intent and recovering that in my OpenHelper class, but it is not working. Honestly, I don't know if that is correct, so I am looking for your help.

How could I get a string and use it as my tables names?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

Here I get the string, the name of the table. It works!

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(ColetaListaActivity.this, OpenHelper.class);
                        intent2.putExtra("nomelista", nomeLista);
                        startActivity(intent2);
```

Here is my OpenHelper:

Actually it say that need a method for getIntent. And I dont know what to do.

```
public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "codigoslista.db";
    private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;
    public String nomelistafinal;

    public OpenHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //pega nome da lista
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        nomelistafinal = bundle.getString("nomelista");

        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CODIGOS(codigo text not null) ");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + nomelistafinal + "(codigo text not null) ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE CODIGOS");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + nomelistafinal);

        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just instantiate your database class in your activity

```
OpenHelper mOpenHelper = new OpenHelper(this);
```

And create a method in your db class to create your tables

```
public void createTable(String nomelistafinal ) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + nomelistafinal + " (codigo text not null) ");
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenHelper isn't an Activity so you can't start it as if it were an Activity. As it's not an Activity or inherited from an Activity it doesn't have **getIntent** method.

You need to have another activity say StoreData then
-  start that Activity, 
- get the intent extra(s) in that Activity's **onCreaate** method
= instantiate an OpenHelper object, again in or via the **onCreate** method
- you can then access the tables in the database via that 
  -  eg store the data input in that activity
- you would also need to remove the attempt to get the Intent extras.

### EXAMPLE

The following is a simple example that passes a String (the value being *mydata*) from the **List** activity to the **StoreData** activity.

The **StoreData** activity which allows the user to enter some data in an edit text and then click the SAVE DATA button.

Clicking the **SAVE DATA** button will store the text that was passed via the intent (*mydata*) concatenated with the data that the user entered (if clicking with nothing entered then row will not be added and the Toast will indicated this). If the row is successfully added, then a Toast confirms this.

Ther is another button **LOG DATA (if any)**, if this is clicked and there is any rows that have been saved the data will be written to the Log using the DataBaseUtils **dumpCursor** method.

e.g. :0-

```
2019-01-19 16:56:26.166 7477-7477/mjt.test001 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@8f5d8ba
2019-01-19 16:56:26.167 7477-7477/mjt.test001 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-19 16:56:26.167 7477-7477/mjt.test001 I/System.out:    codigo=mydataTEST
2019-01-19 16:56:26.167 7477-7477/mjt.test001 I/System.out: }
2019-01-19 16:56:26.167 7477-7477/mjt.test001 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- This indicates that the **codigo** column for the single row that exists in the table contains the value mydataTEST (i.e. mydata was passed via the Intent, TEST was input by the user).

The code is as follows

### List.java (List Activity) :-

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,StoreData.class);
        i.putExtra("nomelista","mydata");
        // NOTE starts the 2nd activity straight away
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

### OpenHelper.java (see comments) :-

```
public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "codigoslista.db";
    private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;
    public static String nomelistafinal = "the_table_name"; //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED

    public OpenHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //pega nome da lista
        //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); //<<<<<<<<< COMMENTD OUT
        //nomelistafinal = bundle.getString("nomelista"); //<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT

        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CODIGOS(codigo text not null) ");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + nomelistafinal + "(codigo text not null) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE CODIGOS");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + nomelistafinal);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Store some data
     * @param codigo
     * @return the rowid of the inserted row
     */
    public long storeData(String codigo) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("codigo",codigo);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.insert(nomelistafinal,null,cv);
    }

    /**
     * Dump all data from the nomlistafinal table
     */
    public void logData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(nomelistafinal,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

### StoreData (2nd Activity)

```
public class StoreData extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mMyData;
    Button mSave, mLogData;
    OpenHelper mOpnHlpr;
    String mCurrentNomlist;
    long mLastIDAdded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_data);
        mMyData = this.findViewById(R.id.mydata);
        mSave = this.findViewById(R.id.save);
        mOpnHlpr = new OpenHelper(this);
        mCurrentNomlist = getIntent().getStringExtra("nomelista");
        setupUI();
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        mMyData = this.findViewById(R.id.mydata);
        mSave = this.findViewById(R.id.save);

        // Add the OnClick Listener
        mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Do nothing if there is no data
                if (mMyData.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(StoreData.this, "Not Added as there is nothing to add.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // Otherwise addd a row
                if ((mLastIDAdded = mOpnHlpr.storeData(mCurrentNomlist + mMyData.getText().toString())) > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(StoreData.this,"Added row with an ID of " + String.valueOf(mLastIDAdded),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        mLogData = this.findViewById(R.id.logdata);
        mLogData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mOpnHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),OpenHelper.nomelistafinal) > 0) {
                    mOpnHlpr.logData();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```